# raspian Buster can't connect to eduroam wpa_supplicant v.2.8

Tags: raspberry-pi, wifi, wpa-supplicant

Hey Guys I would like to connect the raspberry pi of our universits (hs-augsburg) to the eduroam network. I am usind the Wpa_supplicant version 2.8. I can't /don't know how to upgrade to the version 2.9. I changed the wpa_supplican.conf to (User and password replaced,the login data is correct tested it on another device):

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=DE

network={
   ssid="eduroam"
   proto=RSN
   key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
   eap=PEAP
   identity="USER@hs-augsburg.de"
   password="PASSWORD"
   phase1="peaplabel=0"
   phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
}
```

if i start the wpa_supplicant it tries to connect but failes:

> sudo wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

Error:

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Failed to create interface p2p-dev-wlan0: -16 (Device or resource busy)
nl80211: Failed to create a P2P Device interface p2p-dev-wlan0
P2P: Failed to enable P2P Device interface
wlan0: Trying to associate with SSID 'eduroam'
wlan0: Associated with 70:3a:0e:64:b3:f0
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=21 -> NAK
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=70:3a:0e:64:b3:f0 reason=23 locally_generated=1
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="eduroam" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=AUTH_FAILED
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=DE
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="eduroam"
```